# Network Activation fails for wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, ethernet, dhcp

I have a BrosTrend AC3L device.  It worked initially an then I patched to latest 20.04 and it seems to have developed this behaior.  The devices comes up and connects to the network and then fails to activate.  The light on the usb wifi device are lite and it is on the network but somewhere network manager or systemd is not enabling it.  Strangely if I connect another home router to the ethernet port on my system and allow it to get an address on that network the wifi then works. The ethernet system having no external access but working DHCP.  Seems to heal the wifi.  So now I have a sad work around of running a router with an ethernet link just to heal th wifi on my workstation.  I can't see the error.  Clearly something in dhcp or the wifi client config is broken.  It isn't my network or I would just put up and static and hard code the interface.  I hate wifi.

```
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2926] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): Activation: starting connection 'mayasgarden5_1' (1ec77a3e-3a2a-42b2-9789-14cbed923cf3)
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2927] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2931] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2935] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): Activation: (wifi) access point 'mayasgarden5_1' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2935] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2937] sup-iface[0x556a2ed670f0,wlx7ca7b0be521e]: wps: type pbc start...
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2953] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2955] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2959] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): Activation: (wifi) connection 'mayasgarden5_1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2959] Config: added 'ssid' value 'mayasgarden5_1'
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2959] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2959] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2959] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2959] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921322.2959] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews wpa_supplicant[2649]: wlx7ca7b0be521e: Trying to associate with f4:f2:6d:8a:a6:8f (SSID='mayasgarden5_1' freq=5180 MHz)
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews wpa_supplicant[2649]: wlx7ca7b0be521e: Association request to the driver failed
Jun 23 07:08:42 xopherews wpa_supplicant[2649]: wlx7ca7b0be521e: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mayasgarden5_1" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jun 23 07:09:07 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <warn>  [1592921347.8995] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jun 23 07:09:07 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921347.8996] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 07:09:08 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <warn>  [1592921348.6714] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): Activation: failed for connection 'mayasgarden5_1'
Jun 23 07:09:08 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921348.6716] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 23 07:09:08 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921348.6717] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jun 23 07:09:08 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921348.6764] device (wlx7ca7b0be521e): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 07:09:08 xopherews wpa_supplicant[2649]: wlx7ca7b0be521e: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jun 23 07:09:15 xopherews NetworkManager[16382]: <info>  [1592921355.0600] manager: startup complete
```

Comment: They are claiming there is a regression in the kernel with a fix upstream but not yet in ubuntu.  I have tried rolling just the kernel back so I actually think it is somewhere in the OS but I have given up on the card and ordered something less questionable.